# Scanner import issue apparently

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("You will be prompted to enter the lengths of your triangle, do this in no particular order");

        *Scanner sc = new.Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error on the marked `Scanner` line? I've done this countless times. It keeps telling me it needs an identifier. What's going on?

Comment: `*Scanner sc = new.Scanner(System.in);` should be `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: use : `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: sigh. how did I miss this. thanks for the swift response. love this place.

Comment: For a moment, I thought you're trying to do C++ pointers in Java. Welcome to SO! **BTW,** it's better to "mark lines" using the language's own commenting styles (in Java: `doSomething() //why doesn't this work?`). We misread your `*` marking as another mistake you're making.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Not

```
Scanner sc = new.Scanner(System.in); // . is invalid
```

`.` should replace with a space. there is no `*` aswell

Answer (score 0):

I had made a simple error. The corrected code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication1 {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println ("You will be prompted to enter the lengths of your triangle, do this in no particular order");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```